# Database connection problems in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, connection

When I run the script below with the added line,

```
$count = 1;
```

I get a value of 1 on the screen, but when I take that line out I don't get get anything at all.  tried moving it above the $count=mysql_num_rows($result); and I still didn't get a value.

```
$sql="SELECT EMAIL FROM CUSTOMER WHERE email='$myemail' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

$count = 1;
echo $count;
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have never used PHP until now. The error is:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Comment: Change the second line to `$result=mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() );` so you'll see any SQL error messages.

Comment: Seems like your connection is failing

Comment: Thanks, I used die( mysql_error() ); and it reported this error. I am using the same connection on a different page and it works fine.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysql). If you care to learn, [here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) is a quite good PDO-related tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

This means that your MySQL server socket (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock) is either missing or corrupt.

It could also mean that MySQL service is not working right, try restarting in SSH using:

```
$ service mysqld restart
```

If it says the service is missing, then say:

```
$ service mysql restart
```

Comment: I have another page that works fine on the database, I am in the process of redoing the current page based on the working one.. hopefully it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess at an a error with your SQL query (`var_dump($count);` would return false in this case).

To check this, I would do 2 things:

- After your query do `if(!$result) echo mysql_error( );` - this will show you any errors that happen while talking to the database
- To check your SQL is being formed correctly, create it in a variable (e.g. `$sql = "SELECT email ...";`) and echo it out.

EDIT: Ahh just seen the update - it's a connection issue. Check that your `mysql_connect( )` has the right host, username & password. Otherwise it could be a problem on your system (e.g. firewall or similar)

EDIT 2: As has been rightly pointed out, mysql_connect details would cause a different connection error to the one you're seeing. I've had a quick Google for it, and this cropped up http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/204035. Not sure it'll be any use as I've not read it through, but it does describe some steps for the solving this problem on someone else's system.

Comment: If the mysql_connect function had invalid information, it would not return a socket error.

Comment: Right y'are, I'll get rid of that bit!

Answer (score 0):

When you can't connect successfully to the database, return value from `mysql_query` function ($result) would not be a valid value. so when you give it to `mysql_num_rows` function, it fails & returns FALSE value, which has no visual effect on output screen!